# Pass form values to java class when JS validation returns true

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am looking to know how to pass form values from an html from in a jsp page to a Java class when the JavaScript form validation returns true.

HTML code:

```
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return loginValidation()>
 <p class="error" id="liusrError"></p>
 <label for="usr">Username :</label>
 <br /> 
 <input type="text" name="liusr" id="liusr"> 
 <br />
 <p class="error" id="lipwdError"></p>
 <label for="pwd">Password :</label> <br /> 
 <input type="password" name="lipwd" id="lipwd">
 <br /> 
 <a id="fgtpwd" href="url">Forgot your password?</a> 
 <br /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="logIn">
</form>
```

The JavaScript:

```
function loginValidation(){
 var pwd = document.getElementById("lipwd").value;
 var usr = document.getElementById("liusr").value;
 var error = false;

 if(pwd == null || pwd == ""){
  document.getElementById("lipwdError").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid password";
  error = true;
 }else{
  document.getElementById("lipwdError").innerHTML = " ";
 }

 if(usr == null || usr==""){
  document.getElementById("liusrError").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid username";
  error = true;
 }else{
  document.getElementById("liusrError").innerHTML = " ";
 }

 return error;
}
```

EDIT:

I want to know how to use this `<% if ( request.getParameter("liusr") != null ) { %>` to send the values entered in my form to my Java class only when the JavaScript function `loginValidation` returns true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have your `<form>` actually POST it's contents to a URL when validation is complete:

```
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return loginValidation()" 
    method="POST" action="/login">
```

And then your Java class should be mapped to handle POST requests to `/login`.

Comment: Would that still work if in my Java class I wanted to validate if the username and password is correct. If the details are not correct is it possible to output an error to the same login form with the values entered by the user still entered.

Comment: the `method` and `action` attributes of the `form` tell the browser to submit the form contents to that URL as long as `onsubmit` returns true. You can do whatever you want inside that Java class. In fact, you should validate those same fields are non-empty/correct since it's possible some users of yours could have Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your form submit behaviour to depend on your own function you must use:

```
onsubmit="return yourfunction()"
```

As you use onsubmit="yourfunction" it does not affect default behaviour, because your function returns a value, but onsubmit does not care of it in this case :)

So your code should look like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" onsubmit="return loginValidation()>
```